# Problem with the site introductory text

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-attributes

The following text is shown to non logged in users. Italic is mine.

> ### Welcome New User
>
> Programmers is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for people who love *indirectly relate to programming*. It's 100% free, no registration required.

I guess the usual text concatenation approach is useless here. :)

Comment: Related: [Grammer of Off topic close reason](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/117/grammer-of-off-topic-close-reason)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed to

> Programmers is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for professional topics related to programming. It's 100% free, no registration required.

for more, see the [faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest:

> ## Welcome New User
>
> Programmers is a collaboratively edited question and
>   answer site for people who love
>   anything which indirectly relates to
>   programming. It's 100% free, no
>   registration required

Simple, but effective... `:-)`